# Why DARPA wants secure messaging based on blockchain

Tags: blockchain, whisper

DARPA (US Defense Advanced Research Projects Agency) has released a Request for Proposal for a Secure Messaging Platform using a blockchain framework.

The following is the Objective paragraph from DARPA's call for proposal:

> OBJECTIVE: Create a secure messaging and transaction platform that separates the message creation, from the transfer (transport) and reception of the message using a decentralized messaging backbone to allow anyone anywhere the ability to send a secure message or conduct other transactions across multiple channels traceable in a decentralized ledger.

The request for proposal is available in full, here:
[DARPA Call for Proposal for Secure Messaging Platform.](http://pastebin.com/raQafuTm)

- Why are contemporary secure messaging platforms like TextSecure, Cryptocat, XMPP/OTR, Bitmessaging and so many more NOT enough?

  - What do these contemporary solutions lack, as the [Secure Messaging Scorecard](https://www.eff.org/node/82654) suggests many applications have all these features?
- What does blockchain provide when it comes to Secure Messaging and why it is necessary?

How can Military Interdepartmental Purchase Requests (MIPR) be implmented using the secure ledger or blockchain?

In particular, this paragraph of the proposal is not making sense to me

`The messaging platform would act as the transport for a cyptographically sound record of all transactions whether they be MIPRs, contracts, troop movements or intelligence. Troops on the ground in denied communications environments would have a way to securely communicate back to HQ and DoD back office executives could rest assured that their logistics system is efficient, timely and safe from hackers. The benefits are broad and could even be applied to domains such as space. With crowded skies it’s important to maintain situational awareness of all satellites and those concerned with space situational awareness/telemetry or air traffic control could instantly share data between nations using a separate but equivalent ledger implementation thus removing questions as to the authenticity and integrity of the data.`

What does `transport` mean here?
How does blockchain help troops communicate in denied communication environment?
I am also not clear about the argument on situational awareness of satellites and how does blockchain enable sharing data between nations.

Simple answers would really help me and others like me. Thanks